# using variable within sed on lines that match pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to execute the following command and sed is not liking it. I'm sure the fix is simple but I haven't found any solutions yet.

On lines that don't begin with http, I'm trying to place the contents of $currentlink at the beginning of the line. Sed is throwing an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated--thanks!

```
sed '/^http/!s/^/$currentlink\//g'
```

Comment: Did I get you right that $currentlink is a variable in a shell script?

Comment: yes, this is a bash shell variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

> sed '/^http/!s@^@'"$(echo ${currentlink}|sed 's/@/\\@/g')/"'@'

Comment: This solution will be broken if the $currentlink contains '#'. Keep this in mind

Comment: I think this quoting might work better: `sed '/^http/! s@^@'"${currentlink}/"'@g'`

Comment: Yes, but one may have `@` in a query part of the link. The most correct way is this: `sed '/^http/!s@^@'"$(echo ${currentlink}|sed 's/@/\\@/g')/"'@'`. I updated the answer.

Comment: P.S. the `g` option to the `s` command in your sample is irrelevant as you do the replacement of a match that is at the beginning of line. But in my last version in the 'inner' sed invocation it is important as it has to replace `all` '@' symbols in a link

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes don't interpolate shell variables. There are several options, one of them is to use double quotes.

```
sed -e "/^http/!s/^/$currentlink/"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution and am receiving:
    sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'